# Struct one-liner

Tags: matlab, struct

```
>> a=dir('*.slx')

a = 

4x1 struct array with fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum

>> a(1).directory=pwd

a = 

4x1 struct array with fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
    directory
```

Is there a one-liner that can fill in the directory for array elements 2+? Seeking to avoid use of looping (for, while, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the function [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
[a.directory] = deal(pwd);
```

Comment: Works well... very clever!